# Редактор CKEditor

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Для редактирования текстов на сайте у нас используется плагин CKEditor. У него в выпадающем списке "Форматирование" есть несколько видов форматов заголовков и т.п. Мне надо из этого списка убрать все заголовки, кроме одного. Не подскажете, где это настраивается?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В config.js:

```
config.format_tags = 'h1;h2;pre;address'
```